# Win + D no longer brings me to dekstop screen

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 32-bit.

I don't know exactly how this happened but pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> no longer minimises all my windows and brings me to desktop. Instead, it opens the search box and searches for <kbd>D</kbd> (experienced both on file manager and Firefox).

Please help me correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open "System settings", go to "keyboard", click the "shortcuts" tab. Select navigation in the left pannel. Scroll down to "Hide all normal windows"

This is your shortcut. Click it and enter a new combination if you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

It should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Changing it to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> wouldn't be a good idea, since <kbd>Super</kbd> opens the overview (it might even be impossible).

Comment: I have used it ever since I installed Ubuntu. This behaviour has started recently. AFAIK its the same for Windows too and I'm habituated with it. Can you tell me how do I set it to use Super + D to return to my desktop?